# Is that possible to copy a folder without zipping from Google Cloud Storage to Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-workspace

Colab don't like to use a simple copy like this :

!gsutil cp gs://Bucket/Folder_to_be_copied Destination_colab

Should I add -r ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mounting the bucket to the colab makes it easier for you. You can use the regular linux commands in the place of gsutil commands. These are the steps for mounting the bucket in colab.

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Once you run this, a link will be generated, you can click on it and get the signing in done.

```
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
!apt -qq update
!apt -qq install gcsfuse
```

Use this to install gcsfuse on colab. Cloud Storage FUSE is an open source FUSE adapter that allows you to mount Cloud Storage buckets as file systems on Colab, Linux or macOS systems.

```
!mkdir folderOnColab
!gcsfuse folderOnBucket/content/folderOnColab
```

Use this to mount the directories.

You can use this docs for further reading. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

Answering you question, GSUtil can be used to copy entire directories without zipping its content. And your command looks fine. I wonder what the Destination_colab part in your command is.